# How do you do multiple AJAX requests without multiple database connections?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm creating a web page with select elements which are populated dynamically by AJAX requests.

Upon some event, a select element makes a request to a script which upon execution makes a database connection, queries the database and responds with the data received which will then populate the select element. Each select element makes a separate request at separate events.

In this case, are multiple database connections a bad idea and is there a way to avoid them? I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Multiple connections are only bad if there's so many you hit the connection limit and requests start failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only making a few requests per page or per time then this won't be overly expensive. If its a very busy page or site then make a connection pool and share between sessions.

One thing: from your description it sounds like you're letting the page generate SQL on the fly. This sounds like a recipe for an injection attack. Make sure you sanitize the AJAX before you apply it.

Comment: I thought it was very important to limit the number of queries used per page and that this was more important than the number of joins used.

Comment: If you're worried about the number of queries used by a specific page then throttle this is a session variable. Since you haven't said much about what the page(s) will do a lot of this is speculation.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple connection don't do any harm. Depending on your webserver and database type it can vary but the default maximum connections is 151 as you can see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html). If you exceed this number you will receive a `Too many connections` error which means that all available connections are in use by other clients.

> The number of connections permitted is controlled by the
>   max_connections system variable. The default value is 151 to improve
>   performance when MySQL is used with the Apache Web server.
>   (Previously, the default was 100.) If you need to support more
>   connections, you should set a larger value for this variable.

If you make a proper connection that fetches and returns the data, this should be done in a few miliseconds, so chances are very small that you will have 151 concurrent open connections that are all working on a query.

So no.. This is not a problem.

Comment: I thought it was very important to limit the number of queries used per page and that this was more important than the number of joins used.

Comment: Obviously it is better to do the minimum queries possible. So rather than doing 10 queries to retrieve 10 fields from the same table, it is better to fit them all into one query.  But I guess that speaks for itself. If you use common sense when writing proper, optimized queries, the maximum number of connections will never be of any concern for you.